# My following element style won't change beyond a certain point (CSS3)

Tags: html, css, position, element, portfolio

So I've created a personal portfolio website and beyond the actual portfolio grid I simply cannot style properly anything else. It's extremely restricted and I've only just managed to be able to get anything beyond it!

I've tried for days (I'm still learning) to get this resolved and had very very slow progress.

I've succumbed and decided a wiser man or woman would probably know very quickly what I'm doing wrong.

**here is the live website with the code below:**

http://www.hghazni.com/v2/index.html

**And here is the CSS/HTML:**

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
}

.nav-main {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 3.0em;
  line-height:35px
}

.under-logo {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  line-height:40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

.title {
  height: 50em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Open sans, Tahoma, Arial;
  background: url(http://hghazni.com/v2/img/flat_mountain_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  /*background-color: #ee712b;*/
  background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  overflow: visible;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%*/

}

.title img {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*margin: auto;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
.title h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 4em;
  /*position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;*/
}

.title h2 {
  /*background-color:#000;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;*/
  position: absolute;
  top:82.5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.content h3 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.work-header {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #343436;
}

/*Portfolio Header*/

.work-header h1 {
  font-size: 4.2em;
  color: #fff;
}

#brain {
  color: #e4c027;
}
#heart {
  color: #f90446
}
#soul {
  color: #6442e9
}

/*Portfolio Grid Section baby*/

.work {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 92%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.work h1 {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-right: 6em;
}

.box {
   float:left;
   position: relative;
   width: 28%;
   padding-left: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
   background-color: #fff;
}
.boxInner {
   position: relative;
   left: 20px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   background: #000;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
   margin-bottom: 1em;
   height: 3em;
   padding-top: 1em;
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

/*contact page*/

.work parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;

}
.work parent contact {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work parent contact h1 {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
}

.work parent contact h4 {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 50px;
}

/*contact form*/

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
   }

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Haroon Ghazni</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
  </head>

    <body class="no-touch">
    <nav class="nav-main">
      <div class="logo">HGHAZNI</div>
      <div class="under-logo">WEB/UI/UX/GRAPHIC</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#about" class="nav-item">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#work" class="nav-item">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-item">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="title" >
      <img src="img/hg_avatar.png" alt="Haroon Ghazni" />
        <h1>I’m Haroon Ghazni.</h1>
        <h2>A Web Designer from the little big city of Nottingham.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="about">
        <h1>Who?</h1>
        <h3>I am a dynamic and creative web designer with experience of working on international brands in a fast paced collaborative environment.</h3>
        <h3>As a hands on individual who isn’t afraid of a pen and paper I work through the full UX lifecycle from research to design and testing utilising all elements of a user centred design process to create innovative cross platform experiences.</h3>
        <h3>I enjoy learning new skills as well as playing an active part in the design community.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="work-header" id="work">
        <h1>My Work – <span id="brain">Brain</span>,<span id="heart"> Heart</span> and <span id="soul">Soul.</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <!-- <h1> me wurk </h1> -->

       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port1.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Butterfly</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port2.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">La Pura Vida</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port3.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Bohemian Purple</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port4.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Lost in Innocence</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port5.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Cerebral Experience</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port6.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Mario Escort</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port7.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Restaurant iOS App</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port8.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Nottingham Sober Yaught Dragons</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port9.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Poet Farmer</div>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="parent">

       <div class="contact" id="contact">
          <h1>Do not hesitate to get in touch</h1>
          <h4>hghazni@gmail.com</h4>
          <p> HEY HEY HEY asdasdas dasdasda sdad</p>
       </div>
     </div>

       </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm really struggling with this!

Just to re-iterate I want the **contact** part of the website to be less restricted so I can add a contact form and footer!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out,

You have some class without . like `parent` it should be `.parent` and I have changed some style for just demo you can change it to whatever you like.

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
}

.nav-main {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 3.0em;
  line-height:35px
}

.under-logo {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  line-height:40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

.title {
  height: 50em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Open sans, Tahoma, Arial;
  background: url(http://hghazni.com/v2/img/flat_mountain_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  /*background-color: #ee712b;*/
  background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  overflow: visible;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%*/

}

.title img {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*margin: auto;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
.title h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 4em;
  /*position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;*/
}

.title h2 {
  /*background-color:#000;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;*/
  position: absolute;
  top:82.5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.content h3 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.work-header {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #343436;
}

/*Portfolio Header*/

.work-header h1 {
  font-size: 4.2em;
  color: #fff;
}

#brain {
  color: #e4c027;
}
#heart {
  color: #f90446
}
#soul {
  color: #6442e9
}

/*Portfolio Grid Section baby*/

.work {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 92%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.work h1 {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-right: 6em;
}

.box {
   float:left;
   position: relative;
   width: 28%;
   padding-left: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
   background-color: #fff;
}
.boxInner {
   position: relative;
   left: 20px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   background: #000;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
   margin-bottom: 1em;
   height: 3em;
   padding-top: 1em;
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

   /*contact page*/

.work .parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.work .parent .contact {}

.work .parent .contact h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.work .parent .contact h4 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
/*contact form*/

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
   }

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Haroon Ghazni</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
  </head>

    <body class="no-touch">
    <nav class="nav-main">
      <div class="logo">HGHAZNI</div>
      <div class="under-logo">WEB/UI/UX/GRAPHIC</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#about" class="nav-item">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#work" class="nav-item">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-item">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="title" >
      <img src="img/hg_avatar.png" alt="Haroon Ghazni" />
        <h1>I’m Haroon Ghazni.</h1>
        <h2>A Web Designer from the little big city of Nottingham.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="about">
        <h1>Who?</h1>
        <h3>I am a dynamic and creative web designer with experience of working on international brands in a fast paced collaborative environment.</h3>
        <h3>As a hands on individual who isn’t afraid of a pen and paper I work through the full UX lifecycle from research to design and testing utilising all elements of a user centred design process to create innovative cross platform experiences.</h3>
        <h3>I enjoy learning new skills as well as playing an active part in the design community.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="work-header" id="work">
        <h1>My Work – <span id="brain">Brain</span>,<span id="heart"> Heart</span> and <span id="soul">Soul.</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <!-- <h1> me wurk </h1> -->

       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port1.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Butterfly</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port2.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">La Pura Vida</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port3.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Bohemian Purple</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port4.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Lost in Innocence</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port5.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Cerebral Experience</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port6.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Mario Escort</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port7.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Restaurant iOS App</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port8.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Nottingham Sober Yaught Dragons</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         <div class="boxInner">
           <img src="http://hghazni.com/v2/img/port9.jpg" />
           <div class="titleBox">Poet Farmer</div>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="parent">

       <div class="contact" id="contact">
          <h1>Do not hesitate to get in touch</h1>
          <h4>hghazni@gmail.com</h4>
          <p> HEY HEY HEY asdasdas dasdasda sdad</p>
       </div>
     </div>

       </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Hi Majid that's brilliant, thank you! If I wanted to finish the website now that would be perfect!!

Though I wanted to add a footer as well but it doesn't seem to allow me to add another visible section/element after the portfolio/contact section.

I tried to add a <div="footer"></div> but couldn't get anything from that. I've tried to play around and see what's been restricting adding new content by having a look at the positioning of elements (absolute/relative etc) but have had no luck.

Comment: You don't need to use absolute position at all! unless you have a good reason. However, what I saw is just add another div with footer class under  the closing tag of div with work class which means you should just replicate a class or work and change its name to "footer" or whatever. If you got problem share here, and if the answer that I gave lately is ok for you please accept it hope it works for other later when they will search and find it here.

Comment: Hi Majid, I actually oversaw the fact you helped my follow up question the first time around after I fiddled with it! Really appreciate the support :)